# Error At KeyEvent

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I am getting error at keyEvent while implementing snapping. The error is as follows :

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QKeyEvent'
 switch(event->key())
```

My code to Key event is as follows :

```
void Snap::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event)
    {
    switch(event->key())
    {
    case Qt::Key_Left:
    moveBy(-gridSize, 0);
    break;

    case Qt::Key_Right:
    moveBy(gridSize, 0);
    break;

    case Qt::Key_Up:
    moveBy(0, -gridSize);
    break;

    case Qt::Key_Down:
    moveBy(0, gridSize);
    break;

    default:
    QGraphicsItem::keyPressEvent(event);
    }
    }
```

Please help me out to solve it.

Comment: Have you included `QKeyEvent` by `#include <QKeyEvent>`  ?

Comment: Oops! missed that. Thanks error got solved :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should include `QKeyEvent` class :

```
#include <QKeyEvent>
```